# How can I rebuild a widget (with a list) I can't access?

Tags: dart, flutter

I can't update my debtlist after deleting one of the items.

I have a mainscreen with a bottomnavigationbar with two options. Check the list or a general info of all the items. index zero is the list, so its drawn by default.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcBv8.png

In my main_screen.dart, I have a List debtList witch I get from a SQLite database. I pass this list into each constructor.

```
    Widget _getTab(int currentIndex) {
    switch (currentIndex) {
      case 0:
        return DebtList(debtList);
      case 1:
        return GeneralInfo(debtList);
        break;
      default:
        return DebtList(debtList);
    }
  }
```

Now I tap on an item an access to that item info.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rYB0.png

When I click on delete, it works. The item is no longer on the database, but the list is not updated.

```
dbHelper.deleteDebt(widget.debt.id);
Navigator.pop(context, **true**);
```

I've tried to return true so I can check it like this:

```
 bool result = await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DebtDetail(debt)));
    if (result != null && result == true) {
      ...
```

But the method updateList() is in my main_screen.dart class and not in my debt_list.dart class.

What am I doing wrong? I can't update the list in my debt_list class because its final.

```
 widget.debtList = debtList; //cant do this
```

What should I change?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: what is your widget code and state variables?

Comment: https://github.com/NauzetAduen/simple-debt-manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to notify the `DebtList` to know which list item `Debt` to remove. Since you have many actions on `DebtDetail` screen to update list like `update`, `delete`... so it's better to define a DTO (Data Transfer Object) class to pass from `DebtDetail` to `DebtList`.

```
class DebtActionResult {
    int action; // 0: nothing, 1: update, 2: delete

    int debtId;

    Debt updateDebt;

    DebtActionResult({this.action, this.debtId, this.updateDebt});
}
```

Now, on `DebtDetail` screen, we have to pass the result to `DebtList`

```
void _delete() {
  DebtActionResult result = DebtActionResult(action: 2, debtId: widget.debt.id, null);
  Navigator.pop(context, result);
}

void _update() {
  DebtActionResult result = DebtActionResult(action: 1, debtId: widget.debt.id, newDebt); // handle this yourself, because you are adding `final` to the state. Remove the final or create a new `newDebt` state variable.
  Navigator.pop(context, result);
}
```

So far so good, it's time to handle the result on `DebtList` screen.

```
Future<void> _navigateToDetail(Debt debt) async {
  DebtActionResult result = await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DebtDetail(debt)));

  if (result == null) { 
    // Do nothing, no change
  } else {
    if (result.action == 2) { 
      // oh, it's a delete request
      setState( () {
        widget.debtList.removeWhere( (d) => d.id == result.debtId );
      });

    } else if (result.action == 1) {
      // modify the debtList here .. write your code similar to delete above.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwser, I can't try it now but I will tomorrow. Hope it works!.